# Is there a way to disable application to improve performance in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, boot, performance

My Windows 10 laptop has 4 GB RAM and is slow and it loads many applications while booting like Skype, Intel drivers and many more.

I know how to disable Skype and other custom applications but is there a way I can see and disable Windows 10 services which I don't need and can disable to improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

"slow" can be caused by many things.

Download Process Explorer from here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx

Make sure you run it as administrator to see all processes.

If CPU graph is above 3-5% regularly use technique below to determine culprit.

If RAM/HDD high usage check what app is doing Read/writes.

If out of RAM, see biggest memory using apps and optimize/close.

See:
[image: Process Explorer]

Answer (score -1):

You can always use a USB flash drive to make the PC faster as ReadyBoost is a thing today. Open the properties for your flash drive, open the **ReadyBoost** tab, select **Use this device** and specify how much space you want to use, and click **Apply**. You may want to restart your computer as well.

[image: Guide (After entering properties on your USB Flash)]

However, **don't do this on a USB boot disk.** You might wind up corrupting it.

Comment: You can also use the whole capacity of the drive if its useless but if you put data in there then just move the megabyte bar a bit left where it matches the size you might need also! NEVER USE THIS ON ANY USB BOOT DISK OR IT'S GONNA BE CORRUPTED!!!!!!